# Get notified about a page change in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm curious if there's a way to detect a change of the displayed website inside a `UIWebView`. In an app I'm working on we're using a `UIWebView` to present a part of the functionality which are basically a few steps the user needs to follow. However, the will be a specific page at the end of these steps that I need to identify and after which the app needs to display a different view.

Unfortunately the `UIWebViewDelegate` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the user steps are separated on different pages, and the `UIWebView` needs to load the different steps, this should indeed be possible with the delegate methods.

In this example, we say that the user goes through 3 steps, named *step1.htm*, *step2.htm* and finally *step3.htm*. This code will detect when the user reaches the third and final step.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString isEqualToString:@"http://www.example.com/step3.htm"]) {
        // The user reached step 3!
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note that using the `absoluteString` method might not be the best way to find out where the user is browsing. Take a look at `query`, `path`, `parameterString`, etc...

Comment: Oh somehow I missed that. Thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Is there a way to get notified when the new page completes loading? (this method gets called before it starts loading)

Comment: To make it complete, you'll need to get the delegation to the webView as: in ViewController.m:
self.myWeview.delegate = self;
and in ViewController.h:
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 4

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request.url?.absoluteString == "http://www.example.com/step3.htm" {
        // The user reached step 3!
    }

    return true
}
```