# NEST API redirect does not work

Tags: nest-api

I am developing using ios obj-c. I am trying to get the access token using google GTMOAuth2 library. I could do the "work with nest" login but the redirect doesn't seem to work.I see nest animation and it keeps spinning. I have set the redirect to "h..p://localhost" on the Nest Developer Client settings.

How do i get the redirect correctly?
Or
How can i get the redirect to my App itself

Answer (score 1):

We've added sample code for iOS over [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/ios-nestdk). To see how we got the access token from the redirect url have a look at NestWebViewAuthController. Let us know if you have any further questions!

Cheers,
Raymond

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the WebView is timing out trying to load localhost since you like don't have a web server running. On iOS the best practice would be to insert a listener into the WebView that is called when your redirect URL is loaded. See [Get notified about a page change in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834946/get-notified-about-a-page-change-in-uiwebview)